# Can I globally make v-input selection controls use accent color when selected?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am currently upgrading Vuetify from v1 to v2.  I notice that in Vuetify 1 selection controls would get `accent--text` applied as a class when they were selected.  In Vuetify v2 they get `primary--text` applied.

Changing my primary color to my accent color will cause a bunch of other issues.

Is there a way to change the selection controls to use the accent color **globally**?

The alternative is using the `color` property on every single selection control but I was hoping for a easier solution.